# Word mail merge -messing up percentages

Tags: microsoft-word, email, merge

I have a letter that I have to merge a percentage from excel in one field.  When it merges it carries out the number like 15 characters.  I have checked the field in excel and it show zero decimals. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible the cell data actually contains the full number as it is being merged and the cell has a style applied to it which does not show all decimal places? Click on the cell and look in the formula bar.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use formula and add format switch your MERGEFIELD. See examples at this link:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other/formatting-a-percentage-in-a-merge-field/7a62c1e6-250e-4483-991b-3ab40b740443